# Shell script to monitor a folder continuously

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script which monitors a folder (Shared by many) all time.
I want all the information related to that folder like
- Who and When a file is written into it
- Permission check for the newly created folder
- Who is modifying the file and modified content
- Who and When a file is deleted

Answer (score 1):

If this is on a modern Gnu/Linux system, you can use [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) and a `while` loop to write up a simple monitoring script.